# i3 in vmware doesn't share clipboard with host windows-machine

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, clipboard, i3-window-manager

My main os is Windows, I then run ubuntu in VmWare.
Before switching to i3 on gnome, I used Ubuntu gnome. In Ubuntu, I could share the clipboard between the windows-host and the ubuntu-virtual machine without any issues. However, after changing to the tiling window manager i3 in my ubuntu-virtual machine, I suddenly wasn't able to share the clipboard between the host system and the virtual machine. (As a side note, the hotkey for copy-pasting also changed after changing to i3, now it is e.g. ctrl+shift+c for copying.)

My question is: How do I share the system clipboard between my ubuntu virtual machine using i3 (VmWare), and my host windows machine?

EDIT:

Just stumpled upon this [question and answer pair](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=165711) (though it's from 2013), quite similar to my question with the exception being he asks about i3 on arch, whereas I ask about i3 on ubuntu. I haven't tried 'autocutsel' out as the answer suggests yet, do you think it'll work?

Answer (score 5):

[I followed this article, it's content is short, so I just copied it:](https://gaunacode.com/enabling-copy-paste-on-an-ubuntu-vm-on-vmware-workstation)

First, make sure you have VMware tools installed.

`sudo service vmware-tools status`

If it’s not installed, then first make sure you don’t have the open-vm-tools installed.

`sudo service open-vm-tools status`

If you do have it installed, uninstall it.

```
sudo apt-get remove open-vm-tools
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove open-vm-tools
sudo apt-get purge open-vm-tools
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove open-vm-tools
sudo reboot
```

Then, after your computer reboots, you can install the VMware tools. If you didn't have open-vm-tools, you can skip to this step.

Click on Virtual Machine > Install / Update / Reinstall VMware Tools. Extract the VMware Tools tar to the Desktop and follow the below commands.

```
cd Desktop/vmware-tools-distrib
Run this command to install VMware Tools:
sudo ./vmware-install.pl
Follow the prompts to install. I picked the defaults.
```

Reboot your computer and copy/paste should work with the default window manager.

---

### **Since I already had vmware-tools installed, all I had to do was:**

If you use i3 as a window manager, go to the i3 config at ~/.config/i3/config and add the following line at the end. (This assumes you already had an i3 configuration file created).

`exec --no-startup-id vmware-user`

Log out and log back in.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in other answers, you don't need to uninstall `open-vm-tools` (`open-vm-tools` is the supported tool for Ubuntu versions  greater than 12 by Vmware as seen [here](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1022525#install_vmware_tools_in_ubuntu_server_with_command_line_interface) and [here](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2073803?lang=en_US)). Rather executing `vmware-user-suid-wrapper` (instead of vmware-user) from the i3 config file is enough to get the copy-paste and file transfer between guest and host sorted. You can follow the following steps to set it up:

Install `open-vm-tools` and `open-vm-tools-desktop` as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop
```

Next open yoour i3 config file at ~/.config/i3/config and add the following line,

```
exec --no-startup-id vmware-user-suid-wrapper
```

Restart/refresh i3 config and tada, copy-paste and file transfers between guest and host works.

Answer (score 0):

> I used Ubuntu gnome. In Ubuntu, I could share the clipboard between
> the windows-host and the ubuntu-virtual machine without any issues.

First, restart the Guest machine (this ensures a good starting point for the next installation step). See if the Clipboard copy / paste has returned.

In the VMware Menu, Go to VM, and then select Reinstall VMware Tools.

See this screen shot to help you.

[image]

If the option to reinstall is greyed out, then you need to install the Tools manually. This may also be needed in the case for "i3" .  Ubuntu Tools install on a modern version is automatic.

[Manual Tools Install](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tools/10.2.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vmwaretools.doc/GUID-08BB9465-D40A-4E16-9E15-8C016CC8166F.html)

> Power on the virtual machine.
>
> Verify that the guest operating system is running.
>
> Because the VMware Tools installer is written in Perl, verify that
> Perl is installed in the guest operating system.
>
> Select the menu command to mount the VMware Tools virtual disk on the
> guest operating system.
>
> In the virtual machine, open a terminal window. Run the mount command
> with no arguments to determine whether your Linux distribution
> automatically mounted the VMware Tools virtual CD-ROM image.
>
> If the CD-ROM device is mounted, the CD-ROM device and its mount point
> are listed in a manner similar to the following output: /dev/cdrom on
> /mnt/cdrom type iso9660 (ro,nosuid,nodev)
>
> If the VMware Tools virtual CD-ROM image is not mounted, mount the
> CD-ROM drive. If a mount point directory does not already exist,
> create it.
>
> mkdir /mnt/cdrom
>
> Some Linux distributions use different mount point names. For example,
> on some distributions the mount point is /media/VMware Tools rather
> than /mnt/cdrom. Modify the command to reflect the conventions that
> your distribution uses. Mount the CD-ROM drive. mount /dev/cdrom
> /mnt/cdrom
>
> Some Linux distributions use different device names or organize the
> /dev directory differently. If your CD-ROM drive is not /dev/cdrom or
> if the mount point for a CD-ROM is not /mnt/cdrom, modify the command
> to reflect the conventions that your distribution uses.
>
> Change to a working directory, for example, /tmp. cd /tmp
>
> (Optional) Delete any previous vmware-tools-distrib directory before
> you install VMware Tools. The location of this directory depends on
> where you placed it during the previous installation. Often this
> directory is placed in /tmp/vmware-tools-distrib. List the contents of
> the mount point directory and note the file name of the VMware Tools
> tar installer. ls mount-point Uncompress the installer. tar zxpf
> /mnt/cdrom/VMwareTools-x.x.x-yyyy.tar.gz The value x.x.x is the
> product version number, and yyyy is the build number of the product
> release.
>
> If necessary, unmount the CD-ROM image. umount /dev/cdrom
>
> If your Linux distribution automatically mounted the CD-ROM, you do
> not need to unmount the image.
>
> Run the installer and configure VMware Tools as a root user cd
> vmware-tools-distrib sudo ./vmware-install.pl
>
> Usually, the vmware-config-tools.pl configuration file runs after the
> installer file finishes running. If you attempt to install a tar
> installation over an RPM installation, or the reverse, the installer
> detects the previous installation and must convert the installer
> database format before continuing.
>
> Note: For newer Linux distributions, users are prompted to choose the
> integrated open-vm-tools.
>
> Follow the prompts to accept the default values, if appropriate for
> your configuration.
>
> Follow the instructions at the end of the script.
>
> Depending on the features you use, these instructions can include
> restarting the X session, restarting networking, logging in again, and
> starting the VMware User process. You can alternatively reboot the
> guest operating system to accomplish all these tasks.

Comment: As is also the case in your screenshot, the option to "reinstall VMware tools" is greyed out. https://i.gyazo.com/a40dd52f3c3be056c69f52266c5a1de7.png

Comment: Rebooting doesn't solve the issue by the way.

Comment: I amended my answer for Manual Tools Install. This was necessary for older versions of Linux or other incompatibility.